# How can we save all files in (VSCode) like we do in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

How can we save all the files in Visual Studio Code like we do in Visual Studio by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> ?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

It doesn't look like VS Code has a built-in single-press keyboard shortcut to save all open files on Windows.

The simplest way would be to use the menu accelerators: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, followed by <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can change the key binding by editing the keyboard preferences:

[image: VS Code with File menu open, Preferences, Keyboard Shortcuts highlighted]

Add the binding to the right half of the screen, then restart VS Code:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
    { 
      "key": "ctrl+shift+s", 
      "command": "workbench.action.files.saveAll" 
    }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 167):

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>               `// macOS`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>            `// Windows`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>          `// Linux`

Comment: The only trick to note here is that the command key combination `[Ctrl+K S]` shown with menu item text gives an impression that you have to press `Ctrl` key, keep the `Ctrl` key pressed and then press the keys `K` and `S` one by one in quick succession. This is *not* the case. After pressing `Ctrl` + `K` combination release the `Ctrl` key and press `S` separately. For cases where `Ctrl` key has to be kept pressed continuously it will be shown as e.g. `[Ctrl + K Ctrl + O]` (to open a new folder) in the menu item text .

Comment: I'm a Windows user, I wonder why they choose such shortcut CTRL-K S,not the default Windows UX CTRL+SHIFT+S

Comment: If you're like me and can never remember those symbols, that's option+command+S

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+S  KO on my GNU Linux

Comment: On Ubuntu 20_04, Lubuntu flavor, `Ctrl+Alt+S` does not work, but File -Save All works.

Comment: How do I Save All but with format on save?

Answer (score 115):

**TL;DR:** You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +   <kbd>K</kbd> ,  <kbd>S</kbd>  to save all open files with a *little* caveat associated with it.

**Detailed Explanation:** Be careful about keyboard shortcut combination shown in any menu description. There is a *little* caveat to it. The combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> shown as menu description text (Refer screenshot below) gives an impression that we have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, keep the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key pressed and then press the keys    <kbd>K</kbd> and   <kbd>S</kbd>  one by one in succession. This is *not* the case.

[image]

After having pressed   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +   <kbd>K</kbd>   combination, you need to release both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and    <kbd>K</kbd>  keys and then press   <kbd>S</kbd> key separately.

For cases where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key has to be kept pressed continuously, you'll notice that modifier keys will appear twice in the menu description text. For example, to open a new folder, the menu item's text shows  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +    <kbd>K</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>. In this case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> modifier key is present twice (refer screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: This did not work for me in Windows. In latest VS code (1.14.0) I had to press CTRL + K and then release *both* keys and then press S. If I just released the CTRL key then I'd still have K depressed and end up with dozens of K's inserted into the file and no save.  I don't like this at all and will change the binding to something simpler if possible.

Comment: This statement - `After pressing Ctrl + K combination release the Ctrl key and press S separately` means exactly what you are saying. It says after you pressed `Ctrl + K` combination and when you want to press `S` key then don't keep the `Ctrl` key pressed. Instead, release `Ctrl` key and then press `S` separately. We are usually habitual of keeping the `Ctrl` key pressed in Visual Studio which is not the case here. That is what I wanted to emphasize. Once you've pressed `K`key then of course you have to release it to press the next key `S`. You can't keep `K` pressed anyways :)

Comment: Another note for vim plugin users -- to make the double-key hotkeys work, you need to disable handling them by the vim plugin, e.g. for `Ctrl+K S`: `"vim.handleKeys": { ..., "<C-k>": false }`

Answer (score 27):

For windows user -  Visual Studio Code has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>S</kbd>

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.
2. Release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> both keys.
3. Press <kbd>S</kbd> key.

This will Save all modified files in one go. Release is the main point as new user press <kbd>S</kbd> key with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key which opens key board shortcuts file.

Comment: it is hard to remember where release ctrl or where not!

Comment: @KashifFaraz then change it in the key bindings. File -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 25):

For Windows users, the key shortcut is displayed as the 11th option in the "File" menu as:

> Save All           Ctrl + K S

The key shortcut displayed equates to the following:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>
2. Release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> keys.

   Notice the bottom of your window will display a message asking for a second key like this:

[image: VSCode bottom status message after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>.]

3. Press <kbd>s</kbd>.

This applies to other "Close Workspace" command that can be found in the "File" menu (instead of pressing <kbd>s</kbd>, you press <kbd>f</kbd>).

Answer (score 11):

I'm a jack of all trades developer, using lots of different tools and operating systems.  I'm always nervous about blindly using keystrokes.  I much prefer to use a simple "save all" button.

[image: Save All Icon in VSCode]

If you add "Open Editors" in your VS Code Explorer window, that selection includes a very handy "Save All" icon.  Click the icon, and you are done.

No custom keystrokes required.  No preferences to edit.

Comment: Oh, wow, I never knew that "open editors" option was available. That in itself is going to be super helpful.

Comment: That's beautiful. You can hide the other icons using right-mouse-button, so you won't accidentally click the other buttons.

Answer (score 9):

This keybindings.json switches the `Save All` and `Save` shortcuts so that <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is bound to `Save All`:

```json
[
    {
        "key": "alt+cmd+s",
        "command": "workbench.action.files.save"
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+s",
        "command": "-workbench.action.files.save"
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+s",
        "command": "workbench.action.files.saveAll"
    },
    {
        "key": "alt+cmd+s",
        "command": "-workbench.action.files.saveAll"
    }
]
```

Comment: This worked the best for me. I just opened up Keyboard Shortcuts with ⌘+K ⌘+S, clicked the {} icon to open keybindings.json, and pasted in these four shortcut entries. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why there are literally 3 commands listed for this in the key bind editor; "`saveall`", "File: Save All Files", and "Save All `workbench.action.files.saveAll`".

Answer (score 4):

> First of All, I want you to check, What is your VS Code default shortcut for 'Save All' files

[Step 1: Open VS Code> '**File**' Tab > '**Preferences**'> ClickOn '**Keyboard Shortcuts**'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw6H4.png)

> Secondly, I want you to search for 'Save All' Shortcut.

[Step 2: Type '**Save All**' in Search Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy5ao.png)

> Third, you will see that shortcut keybinding to the '**Save All**' Command.

[Step 3: You can also change the keybinding to it. Just clicking on it and adding controls of your choice and then press enter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbFrV.png)

Comment: Why the heck are there three separate ones listed in the key binds, though?

Answer (score 2):

As of May 2020 (version 1.46)
In Mac the shortcut key is:

> Option + Command + s

Comment: Checked November 2021 - still there and working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

**To save all the files in VSCode(Windows),**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then Press the <kbd>S</kbd>.

All files will be saved.

To find other keyboard shortcuts or to change a shortcut,

Go to ***File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts*** OR Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Select a keyboard shortcut and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to update/change a keybinding

Answer (score 2):

- Press F1 or `Ctrl + Shift + p`  to open Command Palette
- Type `Save All`
- Press `Enter`

Answer (score 2):

I'm amazed how nobody mentioned to swap the keybinding of saving just one file to saving all opened files, which is `99,9%` the use case.

To do this, go to `Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts` then search for `save`. Delete the keybinding for the `save` of a single file by right click and then assign `cmd + s` or `ctrl + s` to the `saveAll`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + s

Is supported in latest versions
My version is: 1.39.1

Comment: It didn't work for me. My OS is Windows 10 & VS Code version is *1.65.1*.
It opens file explorere for - Save as!

Comment: ctrl + shift + s is for save as. It does n't save all files even in 1.39.1.

Answer (score 1):

In your Visual Studio Code, on the left side there is EXPLORER and three dots.
Click on them, check Open Editors.
A small window with all open files will be opened (why do they call it Open editors and not open files??).
When the mouse will be on that part, you will see the key Save All.

See pictures for more details

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install the extension: **[IntelliJ IDEA Keybindings][1]**

[1]: https://(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is pressing `Ctrl+k` then pressing `s` without `Ctrl`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick shortcut can be to toggle auto save from File > Auto Save