# Can VS Code automatically update JavaScript and TypeScript import paths on file rename/move?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a module for vscode that would update paths towards files? e.g. if I have:

```
import './someDir/somelib'
```

and I rename or move `somelib`, would it automatically update the file path in all the files where it is being referred as above?

Comment: I don't believe so, but there's a github issue for this that you can track - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19439

Answer (score 51):

This feature was added for JavaScript and TypeScript in VS Code 1.24 ([tracking issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19439))

When you move or rename a file, you will now be prompted to see if you want to update imports:

[image]

This is controlled by the `javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled` and `typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled` settings. Valid values are:

- `"prompt"` — The default. Prompt for each file rename/move
- `"always"` — Always try to update imports automatically without prompting
- `"never"` — Do not update imports and do not prompt

Comment: Requires using TypeScript 2.9 or newer in the workspace. What if I'm using Javascript?

Comment: Same. JavaScript powers VS Code's TypeScript support but if you are just a JS user you are unlikely to have changed the default workspace version

Comment: Is there any way to also make it save the changed files automatically? I find it really annoying that I have to go dig up all the files where the import was changed to save them.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014171/how-can-we-save-all-files-in-vscode-like-we-do-in-visual-studio, which help setting up save all files automatically. In my machine, by default, it is Ctrl + K S, but you can change the shortcut to anything you like.

Comment: @MattBierner Where should I add "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled" in vs code?

Comment: Try adding it in the [VS Code settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

Comment: i'm not sure when, but this seems to have stopped working for me (or perhaps i'm misremembering and it only worked for TS not JS).  require() statements are no longer being updated on moves/renames even though i have the javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled set to always.  Not running a lot of extensions - only the Angular essentials "pack"

Answer (score 19):

First go settings

[image]

Search 'update import'

[image]

You can select:

- prompt (prompt on each rename)
- always (Always update path automatically)
- never (Never rename paths and don't prompt)

Comment: Hmm, looks like this setting was removed?

Comment: no still available

Answer (score 14):

As @jamey graham mentioned, it stopped working for me in a React `typescript` project. The fix was to update the `tsconfig.json` file to have:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    // ...
  },
}
```

and to remove the `"include": ["src"]` option just for moving the files. VS Code should update the paths nicely after this.

You can bring back the `"include": ["src"]` option after this.

I do not know why removing the `"include": ["src"]` worked though.

If this doesn't do the trick, try opening a `.ts` file and trigger the `Typescript: Restart TS server` option in the command prompt and try again.

Comment: strange, your soln doesn't seem to work for an instantiated repo with TS 4.1.2 and VSCode 1.52.1, but when I create a new repo, it works OK...

Comment: Fixed it for me by removing `"include":[],` from my autogened tsconfig

Comment: @joshp Thanks for this comment. Remove "include" fixed it for me as well

Comment: This also fixed it for me. I just left the include out, and I can't see a difference. Doing so caught a bug, too. Somewhere I was referring to an import by `src/File.ts`

Comment: It didn't work for me (vscode 1.79.2)

Answer (score 5):

Import updating stopped working for me after I set up typescript in my project.

The solution was to follow: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66937#issuecomment-475087628

Specifically, to add a `jsconfig.json` file in the root of my project containing:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2016",
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me (vscode 1.79.2)