# Auto fix imports in an entire TypeScript project?

Tags: typescript, import, webstorm

I took some class member variables and moved them into a separate class in another file. Those variables were heavily-used in the project, so about 1000 `.ts` files need their imports changed to reference the new class/file.

WebStorm has a useful [move](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/specific-typescript-refactorings.html#typescript_move_refactorings) option, but only updates references if you move an entire class, function, or variable.

WebStorm also provides [auto-import](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-auto-import.html), but only works 1 single file at a time.

Is there an IDE / plugin / tool that would scan my entire project and update all these references?

Comment: see also [Visual Studio Code Automatic Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210604) and [Can VS Code automatically update JavaScript and TypeScript import paths on file rename/move?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542247) ... and more generally [ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/) and [jscodeshift](https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift)

Answer (score 0):

Before extracting them to a separate class you can use <kbd>rename</kbd> feature renaming to new class and a property name (name with dot is invalid, but refactor will perform replacement anyway). That would temporary make the code broken, but you'll be able to use <kbd>Find and Replace</kbd>. If your new class name doesn't seem to be unique enough, rename to temporary more unique name.