# NX - VScode Moving or Renaming files that are resolved with tsconfig.json paths do not update automatically

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I'm trying to connect an NX project that uses `paths` to resolve library folders.

```
"paths": {
  "@nxlib/mylib/*": ["libs/mylib/src/lib/*"],
}
```

Currently I'm able to get VsCode on a fresh [NX](https://nx.dev/) project to automatically update the import paths of relative files when I remove the `"include":[]` in each project/lib's tsconfig.json (as stated here: [Can VS Code automatically update JavaScript and TypeScript import paths on file rename/move?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542247/can-vs-code-automatically-update-javascript-and-typescript-import-paths-on-file))

Althouth if I start to use the alias path `@nxlib/mylib/my-file` renaming or moving `my-file.ts` does not automatically update the import paths.

Does anyone know how I can get renaming to work with `paths` aliases?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to move or rename a package the best way is using the plugin [workspace](https://nx.dev/packages/workspace/generators/move), because it'll change automatically the name of `/tools/...`, `package.json`, `tsconfig.base.json`...

## Example

> You want to rename the package `app` to `app-v2`.

To rename/move the library/app, you need to run this command:

```sh
nx g @nrwl/workspace:move --projectName=app --destination=app-v2
```

Or if you don't have Nx installed globally on your computer, then:

```sh
npx ng g @nrwl/workspace:move ...
```

---

You can find other commands (e.g. `remove`) at the bottom of the main menu
[image]