# Refactoring: How to replace a type (and update imports)?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, refactoring

i.e. currently we use a type `OldType` from an npm package `@old-package` in our code base.

We want to replace it with our own type `NewType`, which can be imported via `@new-package`.

## Example

### Old imports

```js
import {
  AnyImport,
  OldType,
  AnotherImport
} from '@old-package';
```

should be updated to:

### New imports

```js
import {
  AnyImport,
  AnotherImport
} from '@old-package';
import { NewType } from '@new-package';
```

How can we do this refactoring in IntelliJ, so that the import statements are correctly updated?

Notes:

- I think a simple replace RegEx will not work, because the old import may be one of many on multiple lines
- I checked the [IntelliJ Migrate](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/migrate.html) feature, but it seems this only works for Java code
- I checked the [Structural search and replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html) feature, but cannot make it work for my case

Since this is a on-off operation it's also okay, if this can be done in another IDE or via a command-line tool, etc.

Comment: see also [Visual Studio Code Automatic Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210604) and [Can VS Code automatically update JavaScript and TypeScript import paths on file rename/move?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542247) ... and more generally [ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/) and [jscodeshift](https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structural searching for imports is not supported/implemented at this time (related feature request: [IDEA-285199](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-285199)).
You can try some solutions available on the web, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/refactor-imports?activeTab=readme, for example