# In Git Bash, the command `npm start` returns an error

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, electron

I’m using Windows 10 64 bit and VSCode.

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "shopping-list",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "shopping list desktop app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "YousefMahmoud",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

See the screenshot of the error:

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976870/6330106

Comment: The contents of `package.json` that you posted – is that really the contents of the file on the disk? Are you sure you saved the file some time after adding the `start` script, rather than just changing the file in your editor without saving it? I can’t tell from the VSCode interface screenshot.

Comment: Did you save your package.json to the disk? Or it is just in your editor?

Comment: I did save all files from the file window. but it shown that file Unsaved

Answer (score 1):

When you see a filled dot in front of a file name in Visual Studio Code, that means the file is modified, but not yet saved on the disk.

Make sure to ["Save All" files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42618401/6309) first, then try again your command.

Comment: I did save all files but it keeps showing this Unsaved Files, It is my first time using both VSCode and git.

Comment: @YousefMahmoud Then switch to command line and check the output of `git status`. Are they untracked there?