# Set shortcut for Save All Files in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I set a shortcut for `File: Save All Files` (**NOT** `File: Save All`)? It appears in the command palette:

[image: command palette]

But not in the keyboard shortcut list:

[image: not in settings]

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014171/how-can-we-save-all-files-in-vscode-like-we-do-in-visual-studio)? I'm not sure what the difference is between the two commands.

Comment: Yes. The difference is that `Save All Files` doesn't attempt to save `Untitled-1` and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The internal command name for "Files: Save All Files" is "workbench.action.files.saveFiles".  (I had to look in the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/contrib/files/browser/fileCommands.ts#L74) to find it.)

Here is a screenshot of it bound to Ctrl+A, Ctrl+A in the GUI:

[image: Screenshot of key bindings UI with Save All Files bound]

In keybindings.json, that is:

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+a ctrl+a",
        "command": "workbench.action.files.saveFiles"
    },
```