# R in vscode - saving files command

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

RStudio has an api function `rstudioapi::documentSaveAll()` which I'm trying to replicate when running R code in VScode - is there something like `vscodeapi::documentSaveAll()`?

Comment: Perhaps some insigth can be brought from [this](https://github.com/REditorSupport/languageserver) package

Comment: Also i never use vscode but [workbench.action.files.saveAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014171/how-can-we-save-all-files-in-vscode-like-we-do-in-visual-studio) appears to be the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [R extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=REditorSupport.r) supports many of the {rstudioapi} functions, including `documentSaveAll`. Install that extension and then add this line to your `.Rprofile` file [as described here](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/RStudio-addin-support#enabling-rstudio-addin-support):

```r
options(vsc.rstudioapi = TRUE)
```

Then you should be able to call `rstudioapi::documentSaveAll()` in your code and have it work in VS Code too.

The list of {rstudioapi} functions currently supported in VS Code is here: https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/RStudio-addin-support#implemented-functions